# 'CRLF' not working with sql (Using sql along with lua)

Tags: sql, lua, newline, line-breaks

```
hk=conn:query({live=true,sql ="select DISTINCT O.OrderId, (SELECT R.ReportBody + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10) +'Modified By: ' + UM.FirstName + ' at ' + UM.LastName + ' CRLF ' +'Authored By: ' + UC.FirstName + ' at ' + UC.LastName + ' CRLF ' + 'CRLF' AS [text()] FROM dbo.OrderReports R INNER JOIN dbo.Users UM ON R.ModifiedById = UM.UserId INNER JOIN dbo.Users UC ON R.CreatedById = UC.UserId WHERE R.OrderId = O.OrderId ORDER BY R.CreateDate FOR XML PATH('')) 'OrderReport'FROM dbo.Orders O "})
```

Now, its printing CRLF instead of giving A LINE BREAK,I can't use char(13) either, not working. How can I get this fixed ?

Comment: AFAIK correct SQL syntax is the following: `SELECT R.ReportBody||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||'Modified By: '||...`

Comment: No, that did not work either, Incorrect syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `+'CRLF'` with `+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)` (there are some `+' CRLF '` which I suppose should be treated like `+'CRLF'`)

Anyway, CR LF (carriage return followed by linefeed, `char(13)+char(10)`) is the DOS-like line terminator, the Unix-like one is LF (`char(10)`)

Could it be that the output of your query should be JSON-compatible? In this case, you should replace `+'CRLF'` (and `+' CRLF ')` with `+'\n`' or `+'\\n'` (or even `+'\\\\n'`, depending on the number of levels that use `\` as the escape character).

If, instead, as it seems from your comments, you are in a Unixish environment (lua in Iguana) that gets control characters escaped from SQL, you will have to live with that, by replacing `+'CRLF'` with `+CHAR(10)` and letting the interpretation of the resulting `\n`s happen at a later stage.

Comment: @Simrankaur: you mean there is no line break before `Modified By` in the output of your query? What do you see between `R.ReportBody` and `Modified By`?

Comment: &#XOD;\n , this is what I see with char(13)+char(10)

Comment: @Simrankaur: Well, that means that the `char(13)` is considered "strange" (otherwise it would have been rendered as `\r`), and that you are expected to use the output in a string where control characters like `\n` are interpreted. You will never see a newline in that output, you will always see a `\n` (coming from a `char(10)`). You will have to tell us something about the environment of the query, because the query itself, once you transform `'CRLF'` into `char(10)`, is fine.

Comment: Okay, so I am working on Iguana, which has an integrated live translator for lua language.In my query, i am fetching data from a field called Reportbody from all the rows which have the same orderId and need to concatenate it with modifiey by and authorder by each after a line break

Comment: If my last paragraph is still not enough (I'm unable to help more), my advice is to edit the question, add Iguana to the tags, and, if it's important, award a bounty for a helpful answer. Make sure you add as much information as possible (and reasonable) to your question, though!